# How to show a new event in fullCalendar

Tags: angular, typescript, fullcalendar

I'm using fullCalendar to show a list of events like this:

```
this.audiencias = [{
    title: "Audiencia 1",
    date: "2020-09-06",
    allDay: false
  },
  {
    title: "audiencia 2",
    date: "2020-09-07",
    allDay: false
  }];
```

then i create my calendar like this:

```
this.calendarOptions = {
  initialView: "dayGridMonth",
  dateClick: this.handleDateClick.bind(this),
  events: this.audiencias
};
```

The events are showed good.
in my "handleDateClick" function I open a modal to create a new event, i create the new event and I push this new event to the "audiencias" array, but the calendar does not show the new event, I don't know if I have to render or reload the calendar, I'm using angular 9.1.9, any ideas to solve this? thanks in advance

Comment: FullCalendar took a copy of your array when you initialised the calendar. There is no link between your "audencias" variable and the copy which is held internally by fullCalendar, so updating the "audencias" variable will never cause the calendar to update. If you want to add an event to the calendar, then use the method provided by fullCalendar to do so: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-addEvent

Comment: umm ok i got it, but if i put the creation of this calendar in a function like this:
createCalendar() {
    this.calendarOptions = {
      initialView: "dayGridMonth",
      dateClick: this.handleDateClick.bind(this),
      events: this.audiencias,
      progressiveEventRendering: true
    };
  }
And when i push the new event in the array then i call this function, does it work ?

Comment: As far as I can see, all that function does is create an object containing some options. It doesn't actually create the calendar. You'd then have to initialise the calendar with those options. Calendar options are only applied when the calendar is first created on the page. But it's really inefficient to re-initialise the whole calendar every time you want to add a single event.

Comment: If you want a truly dynamic event source which can be updated, and then have fullcalendar update itself from that event source, then use one of the dynamic event source patterns described in the documentation: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed or https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function

Comment: I recently found the solution, i added the answer to my question, many thanks bro.

Comment: Ah that's good. I think that feature must be specific to the Angular component, I didn't know about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading and reading i found the solution in the documentation, i had to put the angular connector recursively search for changes within my objects, so I just have to set the "deepChangeDetection" to true, like this:

```
<full-calendar deepChangeDetection="true" [options]="calendarOptions"></full-calendar>
```